# Доп. свойства разделов инфоблока 1С-Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте!

Возникла такая проблема, нужно добавить разделу инфоблока доп. свойство типа html / text однако, в типах я не вижу подобной возможности.

Может быть кто то уже решал подобную проблему?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант - можете использовать модуль [Свойства-таблицы](http://g-rain-design.ru/components/tables/), при этом создать 2 колонки - одну типа "Список", где заполнить 2 значения - текст и html, второе - типа "Текст. поле". Правда модуль платный и визуального редатора там не будет. Для преобразования текста в html в шаблоне, если выбран тип "Текст", можете поспользоваться, например, функцией битрикс TxtToHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Как пример. При создании пользовательского свойства для разделов будет пункт "HTML/Визуальный редактор"

https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/d2mg.ufhtml/